# Mitigation techniques for Internet Explorer DOM insertion speed

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

I have a menu with custom drop downs that can contain thousands of items. This is the worse case scenario and most of the time it's in the hundreds or less and it's all super fast.

I've delayed the insertion of the elements (li) to when the menu is opened but this causes a perceptible delay for a couple seconds when it's clicked to when it's opened.

I build a string of all the list items in javascript and add it using a single innerHtml assignment. It's the innerHtml assignment that takes all the time. I've also tried using a fragment and appending to that as well as using a fragment and appending each item separately all to no avail. Insertion times are below:

```
        Text  Li/InnerHTML  Li/Inner/Fragment  CreateLI/Fragment
Chrome  13ms      40ms            48ms               138ms

IE9     22ms      2402ms          2364ms             7934ms

IE11    19ms      1952ms          2330ms             4208ms
```

First column is inserting all the content but just as text and new lines inside pre tags in a single innerHTML call. Unfortunately li's are needed for styling and events ect.

Second column is adding all the content but each wrapped in li tags in a single innerHTML call.

Third column as above but using a fragment and then appending that.

Forth column as above but each li is added as a separate create and append to the fragment.

**Unfortunately IE (We are moving to IE11 around xmas) is the target browser - corporate intranet :-(**

One thing I've tried to mitigate this is to just insert the first, say 50 items. So opening the menu is fast but on scroll, I have to load subsequent items again in batches of 50 up to the scroll point. IE isn't fast enough so most of the time you are seeing nothing and when dragging the scroll bar it keeps locking, jumping forward, locking ect because the innerHTML calls block the whole browser when you're trying to scroll.

Another technique I've tried is to insert the first 50 items, and then load the remaining in 50 chunks with intervals of say 50ms to not block everything. Unfortunately this leads to an even worse experience because the page responsiveness stutters like it does when scrolling in the previous example, but here you don't even have to be scrolling, it always does it until all the items are added.

I'm out of idea's now. How can I make IE work faster?

Comment: createElement and appendChild means I have to do this for each item and can't batch. If you see the times in column 4, I am doing this in a fragment. It is significantly slower.

Comment: Why would loading data with AJAX block the scrolling? Don't use non asynchronous loading.

Comment: Getting the data from the server is not the issue and blocks nothing. It is inserting the data into the DOM that is the problem.

Comment: What's the content of each `li`? How does each `li` vary between themselves?

Comment: <li data-key="some_id">short bit of text (up to 40 char)</li>

Comment: I have found that minimizing the number of elements has the largest impact, followed by minimizing the amount of (complicated) CSS rules. See if you can shave off some HTML tags and/or CSS rules. Try bottom-up: Start with a test page without CSS rules and build up from there, rather than top-down. This helps you find where the bottleneck actually is - number of elements or CSS rules, and which one to what degree? Actually - why don't you build a fiddle test case for us to play with?

Comment: Did you tried spliting objects into smaller containers? I remember some browsers have problems with rendering too many direct children of one element.

Comment: Can you link to a short test-case?  For example, your chrome timings look odd, since in every case I can find, the dom API is faster than innerHTML in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Half-assed answer first: The maximum (for you) is 8 seconds long. You could do a modal overlay that shows a loading animated gif that counts from 0% to 100% over an eight second period. I can link you to some code that does that animation in an HTML5 canvas if you want. This is not a great solution, but it would give your users something to look at while the page is taking so long to load.

Arguably better answer: Do what you suggested to yourself - load the first 50 and then load the next X on scroll or every X milliseconds (I like the former better) and just edit your CSS and other code to make sure the page doesn't do weird stuff style wise like you seem to be experiencing in your tests.

Best answer: You say that it's a custom menu, but it is a menu. As such, you should cache it instead of loading it fresh every time. You create the cache text file every time the menu is changed in the database. Loading a text file into the page will take almost no time and every programming language you work with can do it. The way this works is you make a function that builds a .txt file containing the pure HTML of the menu and then call that function every time the menu update function is run (after the database is updated, naturally).

Comment: I appreciate your answers. However I already show a spinner while it's loading, it spins during the ajax request but stops animating up during the DOM insert. Caching only removes the ajax step and this isn't the problem. The ajax takes, say 50ms, but the times I list are just for the insert (40ms-2000ms depending on browser). So far I've settled on loading the first page, and then subsequent pages on scroll. It's not ideal but at least it removes the initial delay. I hope that the user will use the search box to reduce the results I need to show, rather than scrolling full set.

Comment: While you could be totally right, I'm skeptical that caching will "only" remove the ajax step. I think it'll have a bigger impact than that. Because not only is that AJAX grabbing the data (which it does in 50ms), it's appending/writing the data to the page. JavaScript is fast and all that, but I think you'll find that sourcing a txt file using PHP or whatever is faster.

I can set up a test locally to confirm, but I had a similar situation on another site where caching changed the page load speed from 3-4 seconds to 1 second.

Comment: The times I listed are literally for the innerHTML call. I'm not reading these out of the debugger or anything. Before the call I get time immediately before and after the call to work out how long it took. It totally doesn't take into account whether the content comes from an ajax call (cached or not), a static file, or indeed whether it's fabricated by a JavaScript function. All these end up as a string in javascript eventually, which then gets passed into innerHTML.

Comment: Right, but I'm saying use something else server-side like PHP or ASP or whatever kind of server you are on that is not client-side (i.e. not JavaScript) to load the cached text into the page.

JavaScript isn't very efficient at dumping huge amounts of text onto a page via the DOM, but server-side code is.

Comment: Ooohh. I get what you're saying now. That would completely remove the need for using innerHTML of course. But.. there's always a but isn't there, this is a SPA site. It searches and loads 'cases' (think calls at a call centre) and the menu's contents are dependant on what the case is. We also have case tabs within the site, opposed to browser tabs. Quite heavy use of AJAX already. Unfortunately, these menu's do need to be loaded dynamically based on some variables.  A menu might show 100 to 2000 items depending on the case. The db table with all options is much more massive again.

Comment: Ah, well, if you're dependent on the innerHTML then you're pretty much out of luck when it comes to browser by browser treatment and you're going to have to go with your initial analysis and show the "best" first 100 results or whatever and then load up the rest as they scroll or click through to the next set of results.

Comment: Here's a couple more ideas and then I'm going to let this one go.
You could probably speed it up to a more reasonable level with iframes and taking all of your code on the menu to the server-side and sending posts back and forth between the page and the iframe using the target identifier for the form post.

Also, I've had friends work on dashboards that have similar needs and they've told me that Ruby (and more specifically Ruby on Rails) does this kind of thing beautifully and that it can scale to thousands of items and produce them to the screen really quickly. So that might be worth a look.